# How to write junit test for graceful shutdown in spring boot

Tags: junit4, spring-boot-test

I'm new to code coverage. I have started to write test cases for my spring boot application.

The below highlighted part in red, I'm unable to cover. Could you please suggest how to test these?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ImsApplication.class);
    }

    public static void contextDestroyed(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
            @Override
            public int getExitCode() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ImsApplication.class, args);
        contextDestroyed(ctx);
    }
    

    public ImsApplication() {
        super();
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    }
}
```